# php_fileinfo is not enabling in php.ini file

Tags: php, configuration, server, ini

I am using godaddy VPS having php version of 5.4.33.
Now I want to enable php_fileinfo extension in ini file to avoid the error 
`Fatal error: Class 'finfo' not found` in my php script.
To enable I did the following:

```
1. open WebHost Manager.
2. Go to Service Configuration
3. Go to PHP Configuration Editor
4. search extension directive and fill as `fileinfo.so` in the input box and save
5. restart all services.

6. create a file in the server with the code <?php echo phpinfo();?>. but in that I am not finding any `fileinfo` status. It indicates still it is not enabled.
```

Could you please help me why this is not configured still?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with EasyApache:

In the PHP version selection page, please choose version 5.3 or above, as FileInfo is available to version 5.3.X or above only.

Then, select Exhaustive Option List
[image]

If you don't know anything about EasyApache, you could read the documentation: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/EasyApache

Comment: Build profile, but be carefull ;)

I suggest you download the profile in yaml format, edit it, and then, import it to build and make your own profile and reuse it in the future

Comment: You can find more info here: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/PHP+Module:+Fileinfo